# Unable to find Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary filter under Send Port properties in Biztalk Server Administration Console

Tags: filter, properties, biztalk, esb, send-port

I'm trying to create an OffRamp Send Port for my application here and would like to configure its Filters with values something like -

- *Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Schemas.ServiceName  Equal  RouteOffRamp*
- *Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Schemas.ServiceState  Equal  Pending*
- *Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Schemas.ServiceType  Equal  Messaging*

Although I have 'Microsoft.Practices.ESB' application deployed on my Biztalk Server Admin. Console I can't seem to find any of the properties that starts with 'Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary....' in the filter section of the Send Port properties.

Need help in figuring out a solution to for this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application I missed to add a reference. Must add a reference to the "Microsoft.Practices.ESB" application from Admin Console. Right-click your app -> Add -> References...